# php upload doesn't work in production due to folder permission

Tags: php, windows-server-2003, iirf

I have a php page that receive information with attachment from user and upload it, the page work perfectly local, but when work on production it doesn't work,

the server specs. 
windows server 2003
Iirf is installed on IIS6 instead of .htaccess

while searching for solutions with the technical support i found that the folder where to upload is marked as read only,

i returned back to my localhost and mark the folder to upload on my machine as read only and the same problem occurred, and the technical support agent see that this issue doesn't made the problem and it doesn't affect the process of upload and refuse to remove the read only flag for me

the question is: Does this flag restrict the page from upload files to this folder or doesn't affect?

Comment: I don't know enough about Windows Server but if the folder is read only, how do you expect to write to it?

Comment: @sachleen that how i think, but the agent tells me that it doesn't affect and bla bla bla

Comment: @ahmedsaber111. the agent is right... you need to ADD iis User on your upload directory and give it write access on upload folder. I was also of the same opinion but on server, that is so.

Comment: @RabNawaz so its easy to creating user on IIS, but do i need to do something in my script to give this user the permission to upload

Comment: No, you dont need to change your script. Its about Let IIS Access to your folder

Comment: try that out ant let me know.

Answer (score 1):

http://pt2.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php

Can you try uploading to the temp dir of the production server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the owner of the folder? I guess ISS doesnt have access with the account it uses.